# How to find a mod m when modulus of a mod powers of 2 are given

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need to find the value of `a mod m`.
But I don't have the value of `a` directly. I have the following modulus values of `a`.
a mod 2<sup>1</sup>
a mod 2<sup>2</sup>
a mod 2<sup>3</sup>
...
a mod 2<sup>n</sup>

Now I need to find `a mod m` where `m < 2`<sup>`n`</sup>
Is it possible to do so with this much information?

**UPDATE**
Or if it is not possible with above set then 
can we have some set of `n` numbers for which if we have `a` modulus to all of them, then we can find `a mod m` for `m < 2`<sup>`n`</sup>

Comment: If $m$ is a power of $2$. Otherwise not.

Comment: Are you sure? Any counterexample or proof? I gave a lot of thought on finding counterexample but could not find.

Comment: Suppose $a \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n}$. Then all you know is that $a$ is divisible by $2^n$, but $2^n,\, 2\cdot 2^n,\, 3\cdot 2^n$ all have different remainders modulo $3$, so you know nothing about the remainder of $a$ modulo $3$.

Comment: If you know $a \lt 2^n$ you know $a$

Comment: I got that it is not possible. I have updated the problem. Please see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know $a$ modulo $2^n$, then we know $a$ modulo $2^k$ for all $k\lt n$. So the long list is effectively much shorter than it looks.

Suppose that $m\gt 1$ is odd. Let $a$ be given, and let $b$ be **any** number with $0\le b\le m-1$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there exists an $x$ such that $x\equiv a\pmod{2^n}$ and $x\equiv b\pmod{m}$.

More informally, given the remainder when $a$ is divided by $2^n$,  one knows **nothing** about about the remainder when $x$ is divided by $m$.

Comment: I got that it is not possible. I have updated the problem. Please see it.

Comment: @Shashwat: Might as well make the moduli relatively prime.  If all prime powers $\lt 2^n$ occur as divisors of one of the $n$ moduli, then we will be OK. Another more important way we may be OK is if calculations only involve addition/subtraction and multiplication, and all intermediate results ("$a$") don't get too huge. Then we can work independently modulo carefully chosen $m_i$, and stitch together the answer at the end using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: So it doesn't seem possible to have about log m numbers, which have all prime powers as divisors and are pairwise coprimes. Am I right?

Comment: Why not? The numbers may have to be pretty big. There are good estimates (sorry, no immediate reference) for the lcm of the integers up to $N$ (in your case $2^n$).